# split string into an array and use each item of the array in a query string

Tags: php, arrays

I've searched through all the topics dealing with splitting strings into an array. But I have not actually come across what concerns my needs.

On the searchbox, a user types any string of any length (I cannot tell the length of words). On submit, the php script collects the value as $q.

Example:

1. Let's say `$q="users typed in search query of any length."`
2. php to split each word in `$q` into a `$stringArray` as in `("users","type","in","search","etc")`.
3. php to iterate each item of the `$stringArray` as in: `for(each $stringArray as $i);`
4. Run a query using each `$i` of the array to find matches and display all rows that match any of `$q`.

PHP CODE

```
<?php
require_once('../data/conString_mysqli.php');

if(isset($_POST['services'])){$q = trim($_POST['services']);}else if(isset($_REQUEST['q'])){$q = trim($_REQUEST['q']);}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['s'])){$s = trim($_REQUEST['q']);}else{header('Location:../home/');}

?>

<?php

$stringArray = explode(" ", $q);//split using spaces

foreach (array($stringArray) as &$q) {  
?>

<?php
//run a search query here
$search_query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM service_providers WHERE INSTR(pname, '".$q."') OR INSTR(bizaddr, '".$q."') OR INSTR(bizname, '".$q."') OR INSTR(bizdesc, '".$q."') OR INSTR(pmobile, '".$q."') OR INSTR(pemail, '".$q."') OR INSTR(bizcat, '".$q."') OR INSTR(pmobile, '".$q."')ORDER BY bizname");

    $records = mysqli_num_rows($search_query);
    if(!$records >= 1){
        die(mysql_error());//('<script type="text/javascript">alert("PROVIDERS SEARCH RESULT \n\nCould not find a match. \nTry using one word, exact words. \nYou can search by category. Just type the category name (tv repairs, air conditioning, painting, car repairs, carpentry, plumbing, tiles, rug, washing, catering, cakes, creams, computer, software, hardware etc. \n\nDo not use periods, commas, and other symbols!");window.location="test_array.php?q='.$q.'";<script>');
    }else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_query)){
            $pcode = $row['pcode'];
            $bizname = $row['bizname'];
            $bizaddr = $row['bizaddr'];
            $bizdesc = $row['bizdesc'];
            $pname = $row['pname'];
            $pmobile = $row['pmobile'];
            $pemail = $row['pemail'];
            if($row['bizcat'] ==''){
                $category = "UNKNOWN CATEGORY";}
            else{$category = $row['bizcat'];}
?>
<?php
            echo $pcode .'<br />';
            echo $bizname .'<br />';
            echo $bizaddr .'<br />';
            echo $bizdesc .'<br />';
            echo $category .'<br />';
            echo $pname .'<br />';
            echo $pmobile .'<br />';
            echo $pemail .'<br />';
            echo '--------------------' .'<br />';
            }
        }
?>

<?php
}
?>
```

When I run this code, it returns an error below:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Wamp\www\servicehub.ng\find\test_array.php on line 17
```

Comment: explode() already returns an array (or boolean false on failure), so why are you typecasting that array to an array yet again? and you really should be looking into using a fulltext index. it's FAR more efficient to do a single fulltext search than a long series of `instr()`

Comment: `array($stringArray)` um what?

Comment: @MarcB: They are actually creating a multi-dimensional array which is worse ;-)

Comment: Must....... you...........shout?

Comment: @Fred-ii- WHO IS SHOUTING?!?!

Comment: @AbraCadaver can you say that a bit **louder**? I have a hard time hearing and seeing stuff at my age.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nevermind, I just saw when I scrolled up :-P

Comment: what sonny? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWq1aqDRsOY

Comment: and what about Cher? @Dagon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 17

```
 foreach (array($stringArray) as &$q)
```

remove array and you will have code without that error

```
foreach ($stringArray as $q)
```

Moreover, you can change mysqli_fetch_array to mysqli featch assoc as it will only fetch associative array.

And you can get rid of all that concatenation in $search_query. Double quoute do it all.

Comment: "I have an impeccable international reputation as a master software engineer, programmer and social media evangelist." personally i make a mean toasted cheeses sandwich.

Comment: @Dagon Sure, once you've found the cheese. Say *cheese* :D

Comment: Ok, @Nirpendra, I will try your suggestions. I will come back here whether it works or not. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried your concept. It works. Thank you. But there is still a bug. In the DB Table <Services_providers>, there are several rows of service providers.

For Instance:
<Provider Name>,<Services Category>,<Location>...
On row 1, you have:<John>,<Cleaning>,<Washington>
On row 2:<Peter>,<Transportation>,<Ohio>
On row 3:<Charles>,<Catering>,<Washington>.

Comment: The challenge: if a user searches with d keywords "cleaning services, Washington", d foreach($stringArray as $q) used in the query will return all rows with "cleaning", and "washington" instead of only d rows wit "cleaning" in d specified location "Washington". How can I solve this please? Thanks 4 ur help so far.